# wrapper div not showing content. wordpress in firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, wrapper

I think I prett much explained it through the title but ill try to explain it more.

I have a Wordpress theme that I made. It works great in chrome and IE8 but when I use it on Firefox EVERYTHING in the 'wrapper' div doesn't show and everything out of the wrapper (the Footer and a 'top' div) shows.

Here is one of my template pages, structured back together:

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
                <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>' type='text/css' media='screen'/>

                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

                <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon.ico' />

                <?php wp_head(); ?>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div id='top'></div>
            <div id='wrapper'>
                <div id='header'>
                    <div id='logo' class=''><p>Niagara Islamic School</p></div>
                    <ul id='navigation' class='f-right'>
                        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
                        <li><div id='nav-border'></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id='pre-content' class=''>
                        <div id='introduction' class=''>
                            <h2>Introduction</h2>
                                <?php query_posts('category_name=Introduction'); if(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id='current' class=''>
                            <div id='slider' class=''><?php if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '61' );?></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div id='content' class=''>
                        <div id='news' class=''>
                            <h2>News/ Updates</h2>
                            <?php query_posts('category_name=News'); if(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='footer' class=''>
                <div id='inside-footer' class=''>
                    <ul id='sitemap' class='footer-head'>
                                    <li class='sidebar-head'><h4><?php _e('Navigation'); ?></h4></li>
                                    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>

                    </ul>
                    <ul id='quick-links' class='footer-head'>
                                    <li class='sidebar-head'><h4><?php _e('Quick Links'); ?></h4></li>
                                    <?php wp_get_linksbyname('Quick Links','orderby=name&show_description=0&show_updated=1') ?>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>Coming Soon</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul class='footer-head'>
                                    <li class='sidebar-head'><h4><?php _e('Other Links'); ?></h4></li>
                                    <?php wp_get_linksbyname('Other Links','orderby=name&show_description=0&show_updated=1') ?>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>Coming Soon</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                                    <li class=''><a href='#' class=''>link here</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div id='right-footer'>
                        <a href='#top' id='back-up'>top ^</a>
                        </br>
                        </br>
                        </br>
                        <h4>Call us at:</h4>
                        <label class='phone'>905-295-4845</label></br>
                        <label class='phone'>905-295-0268</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div id='footer-bottom'></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Thank you.

**EDIT CSS**

```
#wrapper{
position: relative;width: 94%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;
}
#content{
width: 100%; min-height: 600px; float: left; padding: 0px;
}
#news{
width: 50%; min-height: 600px; margin: 0 15px 100px 0; padding: 15px; background: #FAFAFA;
} #news h2{text-transform: capitalize; color: #dd771c; text-decoration: underline;}
#news h5{
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;text-transform: capitalize; color: #dd771c;
}
#news p{
text-align: justify;} #news h4{padding-bottom: 50px; text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: this is a (probably) a css problem, can you post the css? at least the `#content`, `#wrapper` & `news`

Comment: I should have given you the address of the website. My bad.

Here: www.niagaraislamicschool.com

Comment: I validated my CSS at W3C and it said no errors.

Comment: repost of CSS you asked for:

`code`    #wrapper{position: relative; width: 94%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;}

    #content{width: 100%; min-height: 600px; float: left; padding: 0px; }

    #news{width: 50%; min-height: 600px; margin: 0 15px 100px 0; padding: 15px; background: #FAFAFA;}
     #news h2{text-transform: capitalize; color: #dd771c; text-decoration: underline;}
     #news h5{padding: 5px 0 5px 0;text-transform: capitalize; color: #dd771c;}
     #news p{text-align: justify;}
     #news h4{padding-bottom: 50px; text-align: left;}`code`

Comment: You can edit your question to add/edit stuff afterwards. Try adding `float:left` to `#wrapper`. Just to see if it works, I know it will break other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, you were right **janw**, it was the CSS.

I had to remove the overflow property from the #wrapper.

Thank you.